# Ask to update value for everycell

Tags: vba, excel

Hey everyone i made a code for an index match between two files but i've got some troubles as after input the name of the file for everycell a window pops for me to update value (select the excel file from which i have to take the data)

```
Sub cacontinue2()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Sheet 1")
Dim lr As Long
Dim mnt As String, mnt2 As String
mnt = InputBox("Filename")
mnt2 = "H:\Documents\" & mnt & ".xlsx"
lr = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
ty = Array("=INDEX(mnt!$R:$R,MATCH(1,(E2=mnt!$E:$E)*(J2=mnt!$J:$J),0))")
ws.Range("R2:R" & lr).FormulaArray = ty

End Sub
```

Comment: Just a note but: `Dim mnt, mnt2 As String` does only declare `mnt2 As String` but `mnt` will automatically become `Variant`. In VBA you need to specify a type for **every** variable: `Dim mnt As String, mnt2 As String`.

Comment: Thanks for the info ;) i'll change it !

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on `ws.Range("R2:R" & lr).FormulaArray = ty` then what is the value of `ty`?

Comment: You don't need to create `ty` **as an Array**. The property `.FormulaArray` is expecting a `String` anyway.

Comment: @MarkFitzgerald the value of ty is ty = `("=INDEX(mnt!$R:$R,MATCH(1,(E2=mnt!$E:$E)*(J2=mnt!$J:$J),0))")`

Comment: @CLR thanks changed it too ;)

Comment: With that breakpoint on `ws.Range("R2:R" & lr).FormulaArray = ty`, if you enter `?mnt` in the Immediate pane, what does it return?

Comment: @MarkFitzgerald maybe i'm doing it wrong but nothing is returned

Comment: I was expecting the return from `mnt = InputBox("Filename")` which wouldn't work because as @CLR mentioned in answer "the address...should take..." a certain format.  `mnt2 = "H:\Documents\" & mnt & ".xlsx"` comes close but doesn't have a sheet name.  Also your formula isn't using `mnt2`.

Comment: Oops! Thanks @MarkFitzgerald I hadn't spotted that! (Changing my answer to use `mnt2` now)

Comment: What would you have to replace `mnt` with in your formula `=INDEX(mnt!$R:$R,MATCH(1,(E2=mnt!$E:$E)*(J2=mnt!$J:$J),0))` to make it workable after closing `"H:\Documents\" & mnt & ".xlsx"`?  You only need the full (qualified) file path when referencing closed workbooks otherwise the `[FILENAME]SHEETNAME'!ADDRESS` syntax should work.  Excel will work out if the file is open or not if you enter the full file path as long as it's valid.

Answer (score 1):

Tricky to test this without spending lots of time mocking up the workbooks but this *should* work - note though: you **need** to include the tab/sheet name that you're pointing at - you can't ignore that.

The 'address' of an external unopened file should take the following format:

`='PATH_TO_FOLDER\[FILENAME]SHEETNAME'!ADDRESS`

```
Sub cacontinue2()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Sheet 1")
Dim lr As Long
Dim mnt As String, mnt2 As String

mnt = InputBox("Filename")
mnt2 = "'H:\Documents\[" & mnt & ".xlsx]Sheet1'" ' Change Sheet1 to the actual tabname
lr = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
ty = "=INDEX(" & mnt2 & "!$R:$R,MATCH(1,(E2=" & mnt2 & "!$E:$E)*(J2=" & mnt2 & "!$J:$J),0))"
ws.Range("R2:R" & lr).FormulaArray = ty
End Sub
```

Note: I have wrapped `mnt2` in `'`s in case the folder or filename contains spaces.

Note: If you want the equivalent of the array formula being written once then completed using autofill:

```
Sub cacontinue2()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Sheet 1")
Dim lr As Long
Dim mnt As String, mnt2 As String

mnt = InputBox("Filename")
mnt2 = "'H:\Documents\[" & mnt & ".xlsx]Sheet1'" ' Change Sheet1 to the actual tabname
lr = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
ty = "=INDEX(" & mnt2 & "!$R:$R,MATCH(1,(E2=" & mnt2 & "!$E:$E)*(J2=" & mnt2 & "!$J:$J),0))"
ws.Range("R2").FormulaArray = ty
ws.Range("R2").autofill Destination:=ws.Range("R2:R" & lr)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks ! It doesn't make the window pop everytime ! Just that if i don't put it like `ty = Array("=INDEX(mnt!$R:$R,MATCH(1,(E2=mnt!$E:$E)*(J2=mnt!$J:$J),0))")` the formula applies to each row with J2 and E2 so I've got the same output everytime and if I put array I've got the right output but the Update Value window pops asking for the file for every row

Comment: So you want the equivalent of an autofill?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone ! after this worked i had the problem of the array being too long ( can't go over 255 char ) if the file was closed so i put something to open the file and close it just after.

```
Sub cacontinue100()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Sheet 1")
Dim lr As Long
Dim mnt As String, mnt2 As String
Dim xWb As Workbook

ThisWorkbook.UpdateLinks = xlUpdateLinksNever
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
mnt = InputBox("Filename")
mnt2 = "'H:\Documents\[" & mnt & ".xlsx]Sheet 1'" ' Change Sheet1 to the actual tabname
Set xWb = Workbooks.Open("\\klxdata\homeshares\klxaero\nbi\Documents\" & mnt & ".xlsx")
ActiveWindow.Visible = False
lr = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
ty = Array("=INDEX(" & mnt & "!$R:$R,MATCH(1,(E2=" & mnt & "!$E:$E)*(J2=" & mnt & "!$J:$J),0))")
ws.Range("R2:R" & lr).FormulaArray = ty
ThisWorkbook.UpdateLinks = xlUpdateLinksAlways
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
xWb.Close savechanges:=False
End Sub
```

It's probably far from optimal but works

Comment: You can get rid of the `mnt2` build line now, if you are happy getting Excel to do it for you.

Comment: Also, instead of opening the file and then hiding the window, why not just turn off ScreenUpdating until you've finished with the file. Looks better but don't forget to turn it back on after.

Comment: The file is opened hiden and after I finish closed so it doesn't bother me much !